# Changing property fill of svg element on click

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm new to JavaScript and programming in general. While doing a little learning project I stumbled upon a little issue with changing the color of SVG elements on click. I have an array of certain colors and SVG element and that SVG should change it's color every time I click on it. Here's the way I tried to do it:
http://jsfiddle.net/j0u3rman/
Could someone point out my mistake?

```
var coatColor = [
'rgb(101, 137, 164)',
'rgb(241, 43, 107)',
'rgb(146, 100, 161)',
'rgb(56, 159, 117)',
'rgb(215, 210, 55)',
'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
];

// Function for acquiring a random element from an array
var getRandomElement = function (arr) {
var randomElement = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
return randomElement;
};

var changeAppearance = userSetting.querySelector('.setup-player');
var wizardCoat = changeAppearance.querySelector('.setup-wizard .wizard- 
coat');
var changeCoat = function (arr) {
wizardCoat.style.fill = getRandomElement(arr);
}
wizardCoat.addEventListener('click', changeCoat(coatColor));
```

Comment: Your fiddle seems broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've simplified your code by removing things I didn't need. Also you must know that sometimes the color will be the same since since the random function may give you the same color several times in a row.

```js
var coatColor = [
'rgb(101, 137, 164)',
'rgb(241, 43, 107)',
'rgb(146, 100, 161)',
'rgb(56, 159, 117)',
'rgb(215, 210, 55)',
'gold'
];

// Function for acquiring a random element from an array
var getRandomElement = function (arr) {
  var randomElement = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return randomElement;
};


var changeColor = function () {
  this.style.fill = coatColor[getRandomElement(coatColor)];
}
wizard_head.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 62 86" class="setup-wizard">
<defs>
  <rect id="wizard_head" x="20" y="5" width="20" height="20" />
</defs>                          
<g class="wizard">
<use xlink:href="#wizard_head" class="wizard-head"></use>
</g>
</svg>
```